# How i can show date of my list in listbox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have list of persons (every "type" of person it's different class) and i would like to show return of ReturnData() method in a listbox in wpf

```
 public class PersonsList
    {
       public List<Osoba> ListaLudzi = new List<Osoba>();
    }
```

Main class of persons:

```
 public abstract class Osoba
    {
        private string name;
        private string lastName;
        private long pesel;
        private string username;
        private string password;

        public Osoba(string newName, string newLastName, long newPesel, string newPassword)
        {
            this.name = newName;
            this.lastName = newLastName;
            this.pesel = newPesel;
            this.password = newPassword;
            this.username = newName.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + newLastName.ToLower();
        }
        public virtual string ReturnData()
        {
            return $"{this.name} {this.lastName}, {this.pesel}";
        }
...
```

```
public class Administrator : Osoba
    {
        private string function;

        public Administrator(string newName, string newLastName, long newPesel, string newPassword) : base(newName,newLastName,newPesel,newPassword)
        {
            this.function = "Administrator";
        }
        public override string ReturnData()
        {
            return $"{base.ReturnData()} | {this.function}";
        }
```

My xaml code below:

```
<Window x:Class="Szpitalv2.ListBoxOfPersons"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Szpitalv2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ListBoxOfPersons" Height="460" Width="668">
    <Grid Margin="10" RenderTransformOrigin="0.537,0.505">

        <ListBox Margin="11,13,212,11" Name="MainListBox" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I tried to use something like below:

```
public PersonsList list = MainWindow.Deserialize();
        public ListBoxOfPersons()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainListBox.DataContext = list;
        }
```

or:

```
MainListBox.ItemsSource = list;
```

But i doesn't work

Comment: `ReturnData` isn't called anywhere. There is no definition for `list` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to solve you problem by overriding `ToString()` method and moving the logic of `ReturnData` to it, something like this

```cs
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"{this.name} {this.lastName}, {this.pesel}";
}
```

in `Osoba` class, and

```cs
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"{base.ToString()} | {this.function}";
}
```

in `Administrator` class. And then set the `ItemSource` of list box properly
 to `List<Osoba>`. When binding is set properly, the `ToString()` method is called automatically

Comment: But how to add it do ListBox then? What it change?

Comment: `ToString` is called automatically. I'll need to properly set the `ItemSource`

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to define the datacontext in the Xaml.

`<Window.DataContext>
   <local:-your datacontext-/>
</Window.DataContext>`

2. You need to bind you listbox to the list

   `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding -your list-}"/>`